# How can I set my range sliders max to be the windows width / 10

Tags: html, slider, rangeslider

How can i make a range sliders max to be the windows width / 10, something like this:

`<input type="range" min="0" max="100vw/10"`

Previously what i had in my code was:

```
<input type="range" id="rangeSlider" min="0" max="100">
<p id="p"></p>
<button id="getValueButton>Get Value</button>
```

```
let rangeSlider = document.querySelector("#rangeSlider");
let p = document.querySelector("#p");
let getValueButton = document.querySelector("#getValueButton");
getValueButton.onclick = function() {
    p.innerHTML = `${rangeSlider.value * 12.5} pixels from the left`;
}
```

```js
let rangeSlider = document.querySelector("#rangeSlider");
let p = document.querySelector("#p");
let getValueButton = document.querySelector("#getValueButton");
getValueButton.onclick = function() {
    p.innerHTML = `${rangeSlider.value * 12.5} pixels from the left`;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="rangeSlider" min="0" max="100">
<p id="p"></p>
<button id="getValueButton">Get Value</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the max value like this:

```
document.getElementById('rangeSlider').max = window.screen.width / 10
```